# Where is the "Data" directory mentioned in the SEDE source code readme file?

Tags: support, data-explorer

The [readme.txt](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/browse/Readme.txt#26) mentions a "Data" directory, in which you can find the basic structure of a stack exchange site. The readme file states:

> The Data directory contains a blank schema for a "Stack" site and the
>   schema for data explorer.

Within the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/browse/) I cannot find that directory.

Furthermore, the web.config requires two connection strings:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="AppConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DataExplorer;Integrated Security=True;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   <add name="ReaderConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=!!DB!!;Integrated Security=True;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The first connection string is self explanatory from the readme.

> Run [migrate.local.bat](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/browse/Migrations/migrate.local.bat) in the migration directory, then import some
>   data about the sites from the [SeedData/sites.sql](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/browse/SeedData/sites.sql) script. It assumes
>   the DB is called "DataExplorer", if you name it differently or have a
>   named instance, you will have to edit the batch file (which I did for
>   the SQLEXPRESS instance).

The following line states:

> Import data into the Stack Overflow database (and any other databases
>   you wish to query) alternatively if a DB exists you can simple run
>   queries that do not depend on data like "SELECT 1"

This connection string can be pointed at any db (which works), but I would like to point it at this empty SE schema.

The readme suggests this should exist but I can't find it. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The readme wan a bit out of date, I expanded it a bit:

1. Use the migration directory to bring up a blank data explorer.
2. Use `sites.sql` to populate with a few stub site records
3. Use something like SODDI to load up the data dump: [Fast Multi Platform Data Dump Import for SQL Server (2000/2005/2008), SQLite and MySQL](https://stackapps.com/questions/2511/fast-multi-platform-data-dump-import-sql-server-2000-2005-2008-sqlite-mysq)

Keep in mind, data explorer will work fine pointed at an arbitrary db, all you need to do is set the `DatabaseName` column in the `Sites` table to it and most of the functionality will work.